# JSON server - Is it possible to update an object id?

Tags: json-server

Here is my db.json :

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "1"
      "name": "John"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to be able to update the user id by sending a PUT request on the existing user. But the following does not work:

Request URL :

```
PUT /users/1
```

with body:

```
{
  "id": "2"
  "name": "John"
}
```

Is there a way to update an object id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem to be possible, as said in documentation:

> Id values are not mutable. Any id value in the body of your PUT or
>   PATCH request will be ignored. Only a value set in a POST request will
>   be respected, but only if not already taken.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PUT request means ,the request URL should be like this "**PUT/users/1**" .

Refer below mentioned image.
[I'm using postman to send put request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrISB.png)

Comment: Sorry, this was just a mistake in the example, but I am doing a PUT request, as described.